# Return pre-defined rows into combo box if SQL returns nothing

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm running the following SQL query to populate a combo box from a data table.

If the query is to return nothing then I would like to retuen a pre-defined list of 3 rows

I've tried inserting the following after the `Refresh` line and also after the `da.fill(dt)` however it just returns blank fields

```
If da.fill(dt) = nothing then
dt.rows.add("list1")
dt.rows.add("list2")
dt.rows.add("list3")
end if
```

SQL Code on GotFocus event

```
Private Sub Op1_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Op1.GotFocus

    Dim search As String = txtUnitCode.Text
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("", "")
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim conn As String

    conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Main.aClients & ""

    da.SelectCommand.Connection.ConnectionString = conn
    da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Operations WHERE (UnitCode = " & search & ") AND (OpIsDead = False)"
    da.Fill(dt)
    Op1.DataSource = dt
    Op1.DisplayMember = "Name"
    Op1.Refresh()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OleDbDataAdapter.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns an integer that is the count of the rows retrieved by your command.
Its value is zero if there are no rows. So probably you should code

```
If da.fill(dt) = 0 then
   dt.rows.add("list1")
   dt.rows.add("list2")
   dt.rows.add("list3")
end if
```

As a side note, I don't know why you want to execute an operation like that in a GotFocus event. Usually this is not a good place for a potentially slow activity like loading data from a database.

Finally, I suggest to not use string concatenation to create query texts. A parameterized query is always the best solution even when you don't have to worry about Sql Injection

```
da.SelectCommand.Connection.ConnectionString = conn
da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM Operations " & _
                               "WHERE (UnitCode = ?) AND (OpIsDead = False)"
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Convert.ToInt32(search))
If da.fill(dt) = 0 then
   dt.rows.add("list1")
   dt.rows.add("list2")
   dt.rows.add("list3")
end if
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks that seems to work however if the SQL does return a value from the query its duplicating the results. I'm current adding the code before the `da.fill(dt)` line but I have tried it after as well

Comment: Hi, Ist possible you could explain this line to me `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", search)` I'm not sure where the `"@p1"` bit is coming from

Comment: It is the name of the parameter. In OleDb the parameters are recognized by the order in which they appear in the command text (The ? placeholder). But when you add a parameter to any DbCommand.Parameters collection you should supply a name (the key for the collection) so I wrote `@p1` but I could write anything but respect the order of the placeholders

Comment: Ah thanks that clearer. I'm struggling with the Sql returning duplicate values (where it didn't before) since adding the `If` statement

Comment: If `UnitCode` is an integer on the database table we need to convert `search` to an integer if we want to use `AddWithValue`